# Typescript Module augmentation is not working: Property 'main' does not exist on type 'PaletteColorOptions'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I have been working on Material-UI and trying to use a color system throughout the palette. There seems to be some issue while compilation although it works perfectly in run time. Can someone help me resolve following error:

Error:

> Property 'main' does not exist on type 'PaletteColorOptions'.
> Property 'main' does not exist on type 'Partial'.(2339)

Here is stackblitz as well: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-up6bjl-hx1bbh?file=demo.tsx

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  createTheme,
  Theme,
  ThemeProvider,
  PaletteOptions
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles' {
  interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
    lighter?: string;
    darker?: string;
  }

  interface PaletteColor {
    lighter?: string;
    darker?: string;
  }
}

const Default = () : PaletteOptions => {

  return {
    primary: {
      lighter: '#ddd',
      light: '#ddd',
      main: '#ddd',
      dark: '#ddd',
      darker: '#ddd'
    },
  };
};

export default function CustomColor() {
  const defaultColors = Default();
  
  const palette: PaletteOptions = {
    ...defaultColors,
    divider: defaultColors.primary?.main, // error in compile. Cannot find 'main'
  };

  const theme: Theme = createTheme({
    palette
  });

  console.log(theme.palette.primary.light);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
        neutral
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: @Danial: if you check stalkblitz, there is error. I want to resolve that error.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The TypeScript error is unrelated to your module augmentation. The issue is just that `defaultColors` is of type `PaletteOptions`. `PaletteOptions` [defines primary to be of type PaletteColorOptions](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-beta.4/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.d.ts#L104).

Here's the definition of [PaletteColorOptions](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-beta.4/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.d.ts#L40) and the types it is built from:

```
export type PaletteColorOptions = SimplePaletteColorOptions | ColorPartial;

export interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
}

export type ColorPartial = Partial<Color>;

export interface Color {
  50: string;
  100: string;
  200: string;
  300: string;
  400: string;
  500: string;
  600: string;
  700: string;
  800: string;
  900: string;
  A100: string;
  A200: string;
  A400: string;
  A700: string;
}
```

So the TypeScript compiler knows that `defaultColors.primary` is either `SimplePaletteColorOptions` **or** `ColorPartial`, but it doesn't know which. You are then referencing `defaultColors.primary.main`, but that isn't guaranteed to be present unless the type of `defaultColors.primary` is `SimplePaletteColorOptions`.

You can fix this by using a more specific return type for the `Default` function that lets TypeScript know that the type of `primary` is `SimplePaletteColorOptions`:

```
interface DefaultPaletteOptions extends PaletteOptions {
  primary?: SimplePaletteColorOptions;
}
const Default = (): DefaultPaletteOptions => {
  return {
    primary: {
      lighter: "#ddd",
      light: "#ddd",
      main: "#ddd",
      dark: "#ddd",
      darker: "#ddd"
    }
  };
};
```

[image: Edit TypeScript PaletteOptions]

Related answers:

- [How to add custom colors name on Material UI with TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430166/how-to-add-custom-colors-name-on-material-ui-with-typescript/68433584#68433584)
- [MUI Override Slider color options with module augmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451008/mui-override-slider-color-options-with-module-augmentation/70537213#70537213)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To make custom palette colors work with MUI components (i.e. `<Button color={'neutral'}>` you also need to augment that component module:

```
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    neutral: true;
  }
}
```

However, I still had some trouble with `Property 'main' does not exist` when using the custom theme value in non-MUI components. I solved this by assigning the custom color to its own typed const and then assigning `.main` to a string explicitly:

```
const selector: PaletteColor | undefined = theme.palette[color as keyof Palette] as PaletteColor;
const colorString: string = selector ? selector.main : 'inherit';
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#non-palette-colors