# MUI5 createTheme - color gradations do not exist in typescript definition of Theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design, themes

I need to customize my theme colors in MUI5, in typescript.  I am using the `createTheme` function to do so.  `createTheme` accepts a `palette` entry in its argument object, which TS says should be of type `PaletteOptions`:

[image]

#### What TS says a `palette` argument can be:

If you dig into the tsdefs on what `PaletteOptions` is, its an object whose keys are the 'qualifier' words for various states, and whose values are `PaletteColorOptions`

```
// From MUI's own ts defs:

export interface PaletteOptions {
  primary?: PaletteColorOptions;
  secondary?: PaletteColorOptions;
  error?: PaletteColorOptions;
  warning?: PaletteColorOptions;
  info?: PaletteColorOptions;
  success?: PaletteColorOptions;
  mode?: PaletteMode;
  tonalOffset?: PaletteTonalOffset;
  contrastThreshold?: number;
  common?: Partial<CommonColors>;
  grey?: ColorPartial;
  text?: Partial<TypeText>;
  divider?: string;
  action?: Partial<TypeAction>;
  background?: Partial<TypeBackground>;
  getContrastText?: (background: string) => string;
}
```

A `PaletteColorOptions` should be able to be *either* a `SimplePaletteColorOptions` or a `ColorPartial`:

```
// Again from MUI's own ts defs:

export type PaletteColorOptions = SimplePaletteColorOptions | ColorPartial;

// Where:
export interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
}

// And
export type ColorPartial = Partial<Color>;

export interface Color {
  50: string;
  100: string;
  200: string;
  300: string;
  400: string;
  500: string;
  600: string;
  700: string;
  800: string;
  900: string;
  A100: string;
  A200: string;
  A400: string;
  A700: string;
}
```

My inference from this is that its perfectly valid to define the `success` or `info` or similar objects using the fine gradations of 50, 100, 200, 300, etc.  This is what I need to do.  When doing so, I get no errors.  The `colorPalette` I fed to `createTheme` above has these gradations, and TS doesn't bother me:

[image]

#### What TS says a `palette`'s properties can be once created

However, I notice that `createTheme` returns a MUI `Theme` object:

```
// From MUI ts defs:

export default function createTheme(options?: ThemeOptions, ...args: object[]): Theme;
```

Digging into `Theme`, the `palette` entry is not a `PaletteOptions` like it was in the argument, but rather a `Palette` object, whose entries are `PaletteColor`:

```
// MUI TS defs

export interface Palette {
  common: CommonColors;
  mode: PaletteMode;
  contrastThreshold: number;
  tonalOffset: PaletteTonalOffset;
  primary: PaletteColor;
  secondary: PaletteColor;
  error: PaletteColor;
  warning: PaletteColor;
  info: PaletteColor;
  success: PaletteColor;
  grey: Color;
  text: TypeText;
  divider: TypeDivider;
  action: TypeAction;
  background: TypeBackground;
  getContrastText: (background: string) => string;
  augmentColor: (options: PaletteAugmentColorOptions) => PaletteColor;
}

export interface PaletteColor {
  light: string;
  main: string;
  dark: string;
  contrastText: string;
}
```

So when trying to access any fine gradations (50, 100, 200, etc) on any of the objects, TS throws an error.  It thinks that the objects can only be `light`, `main`, `dark`, or `contrastText`

[image]

#### Why the discrepancy?

What am I doing wrong in my setup such that TS thinks that the entries in a the `palette` object cannot have these fine gradations, when the *argument* for `palette` says that clearly they can?  Using `// @ts-expect-error` works and the code runs properly, but I don't want to use that every time I access one of these color partial gradations.

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy is due to the intentional difference between what is being created (a collection of `PaletteColor` objects within the `Palette`) and the two main ways by which you can provide information for creating those `PaletteColor` objects.

The two alternatives in `PaletteColorOptions` are so that you can do either of the following:

#### Option 1 - Use imported color object

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { purple } from "@mui/material/colors";

const theme1 = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: purple
  }
});
```

#### Option 2 - Explicitly specify "main" (and optionally "light" and "dark" shades)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme2 = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: "#9c27b0" }
  }
});
```

When you use Option 1, MUI adds in the `main`, `light`, and `dark` shades by selecting the `[500]`, `[300]`, and `[700]` shades respectively (https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.11.10/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createPalette.js#L221). The numbered shades remain in the resulting theme object, but that is just because MUI doesn't remove anything that you pass in, it just adds to it the pieces that it requires/guarantees to be in the resulting theme.

With option 2, the resulting theme does not contain any of the numbered shades, it will only contain the `main`, `light`, and `dark` shades (in my example MUI derives the `light` and `dark` shades from the provided `main` shade). The TypeScript definition for the resulting theme reflects the common output for the two alternatives.

Here's a sandbox demonstrating those two `createTheme` approaches: https://codesandbox.io/s/createtheme-example-z4nei6?file=/demo.tsx.

If you want to use shades other than main, light, and dark, then you can augment the `PaletteColor` type:

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface PaletteColor {
    A700?: string;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit createTheme example]

Related answer:

- [How to add custom colors name on Material UI with TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430166/how-to-add-custom-colors-name-on-material-ui-with-typescript/68433584#68433584)

Comment: Wow thank you for the detailed answer.  The last bit of code you suggested helps to augment the definition of `PaletteColor` to avoid getting ts errors. I am migrating from one color scheme to another, so I need `main`, `dark`, and `light` colors to be distinct from the numbered colors.  But this doesn't answer my question?  Why should I have to manually augment the TS def for `PaletteColor` to look like `Partial<Color>`, when a `Partial<Color>` is already accepted as the argument for a color?  Is MUI trying to be so restrictive that I can't access my own numbered colors directly?

Comment: `Partial<Color>` is accepted as one of the possible inputs, but it isn't guaranteed in the output of `createTheme`. `PaletteColor` is defining the type of the output of the function. Any time you add extra stuff to the theme beyond what MUI guarantees to be present, you would need to augment the `Theme` TypeScript definitions in order for TypeScript to recognize the extra stuff as valid when referencing it in the resulting theme.